# Extracting PO box from an address

Tags: postgresql, actian

I have a column that looks like this

```
Column 1 
--------------
123 Main Street

P.O. Box 1234

PO Box 4569 

P.O Box 4975 

P.O. Box 796 Attn: Lease
```

How do I only extract the numbers so it's only 1234, 4569, 4975, 796?

(Various different PO to emphasize that I can't use a character delimiter.

I tried using left/right and ltrim/right trim but the results are not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple self-contained example:

```
create table test (a text);

insert into test values 
('123 Main Street'),
('P.O. Box 1234'),
('PO Box 4569'),
('P.O Box 4975'),
('P.O. Box 796 Attn: Lease');

smarlowe=# select coalesce(substring(substring(a from 'P.*O.*[0-9]+') from '[0-9]+'),'NOMATCH') from test;
 coalesce
----------
 NOMATCH
 1234
 4569
 4975
 796
(5 rows)
```